# Do HTTP request headers have to be UTF-8 encoded?

Tags: utf-8, http-headers

I could not find anything in the spec which says it should be. I have seen a couple of browsers setting their user-agents to non UTF8 encoded strings. There is however a Content-Type request header which specifies the media type (and charset), and I'm not sure if that is applicable only to the body of the request or the headers too.

Answer (score 2):

The Content-Type header applies to the body, not the headers.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP RFC defines header content as type *TEXT, which is define on or about page 15 as ISO-8859-1 except when the non ISO-8859-1 is encoded pursuant to RFC 2047.

Comment: +1. Note the reference to RFC2047 is widely considered an error as 2047 encoded-words explicitly cannot be included in such a context. The 2047 reference is removed from newer pending standards work on HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTP header field values](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) may contain characters other than ASCII characters:

```
message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
field-name     = token
field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
                 and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
                 of token, separators, and quoted-string>
```

See the [Basic Rule](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2) for the definition of *OCTET* and *TEXT*:

```
OCTET          = <any 8-bit sequence of data>
TEXT           = <any OCTET except CTLs,
                 but including LWS>
```

But in general only ASCII characters are used for the field values as well.